# How to cut a string in a text box after a certain number of uppercase or lowercase characters in PHP?

Tags: php, textbox, uppercase, lowercase

I have a lowercase string in PHP with the value "nbalamuruganbala" in a text box. 
I want to cut the string after a certain number of characters and add suspension points where I cut it. This way if the string is longer than let's say, 10 characters, it is cut and suspension points will be appended.

I use 10 characters as a threshold to cut the string. This works fine with lowercase strings (e.g. nbalamurugan..), however it doesn't work with uppercase strings (e.g. "NBALAMURUGAN..") cause the uppercase characters occupy more space and the strings results longer than the text box.

Here is my code:

```
 $astname="nbalamuruganbala";
                if (strlen($astname) > 10)
                {
                    $astname = substr($astname, 0, 10);
                    $astname = $astname."..";
                }
```

Comment: What are you trying to say actually ?? You need to trim your string at `12` characters and if above `...` these will appear right ?

Comment: use one standard approach only uppercase or lowercase instead of two different case.. still you want to continue in mixed upper and lower reduce the font size

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = "nbalamuruganbala";
if(strlen($str) > 12){
    $new = strtoupper(substr($str, 0,12))."..";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things
1. either display all text into lowercase
2. you can decrease the number of character. As you are saying its effecting other items so decreasing display of characters would be good.

Comment: problem has solved. i reduced character width using css.using this url                                                          http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lower threshold for the number of characters (e.g. max 8) before cutting the string displayed in the text area. This should work most of the times independently from upper or lowercase strings.

**However**, keep in mind that you should never think in terms of number of characters when working with web content. Because the spacing between each one of the characters may vary accoring to the OS, the browser's default font, the screen resulution of the client etc...

A more elegant approach, for instance, could be applying to the text area a CSS style that adds a color gradient (from transparent to background color) so that the string in the text area is visually cut and blends with the background.